# toggle div to show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a simple block of code to hide/show two divs. It works great, the only issue I have is that I need to return the display value to the #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 back to table. I have set it to none in the css initially. The last line doesn't seem to take effect.

here is the code:

```
$(function() {
$('#swap').click(function() {

    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').toggle();
    $('#example_wrapper').toggle();
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ').css('display') == 'table';
});
});
```

Comment: [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is use like $(elemnt).css("property","new value") when changing a value, on the other hand `=` assign a value `==` and `===` compare values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

so your last line should be

```
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ').css('display', 'table');
```

---

when you call **.css( propertyName )**

```
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ').css('display);
```

you are **Getting** the value of said property not setting it

> Get the computed style properties for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

---

#### Update 1:

please note that Jquery's .show(), .hide() and .toggle() will only work with elements with block display property.

so one way to avoid changing the display property back and forth is to wrap the wanted elements in a div (container) and .toggle() it.

[I have created a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/tkfz5y6b/), I warped each div in a container div with a calss called "toggle" and set initial display value of one of them to "none" using style attribute.

```
<div class="toggle" style="display:none">
```

now I toggle between them using this

```
$('.toggle').toggle();
```

---

#### Update 2:

you can also use **.toggleClass()** [here's another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/mh5ot462/1/)

Add this to your CSS

```
#example_wrapper.hiddenDiv, #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2.hiddenDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

add a class to the div you want initially hidden

```
<div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" class="hiddenDiv">
```

toggle the class using this

```
$(function() {
$('#swap').click(function() {
    $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').toggleClass("hiddenDiv");
    $('#example_wrapper').toggleClass("hiddenDiv");
});
});
```

in this example I'm using a class called "hiddenDiv", if you change it make sure the class name is the same in CSS, HTML and JS.

Comment: Thank you for that. It makes sense now. Unfortunately despite that, The inline style for that div is being set to block rather than table! can't see where it's going wrong.

Comment: updated answer to avoid changing display property which can mess up div's style.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `==` operator

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#swap').click(function() {
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').toggle();
        $('#example_wrapper').toggle();
        $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ').attr('style','display:table;');
    });
});
```

Comment: No - the setter of css() takes two parameters

Comment: yeah, I realized that as soon as I posted it. thnx for reminding that btw.

Comment: brill - thanks for that. Silly mistake! Annoyingly, Its still defaulting to display: block after being toggled..

Comment: oh..okay. RScott, I have a meeting in 10. can I get to this after that. I feel terrible asking you to wait.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate you taking the time to help :)

Comment: I updated my answer, if it works, do accept my answer

Comment: Thats great! thank you very much, sounds silly but I've spent a long time trying to get this right :)

Answer (score 1):

you are sure you need "==" to set the value? or one "="

Comment: No - the setter of `css()` takes two parameters.

Comment: Yes it is. Missed it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It would be best to delete this as it's completely incorrect. Im not even sure why it was upvoted to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `==` is an equality check. You should use `=` to set a value.

Secondly, the `css()` method setter accepts two parameters. The rule to set and the value itself. Try this:

```
$('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ').css('display', 'table');
```